# Another UnboundLocalError issue with import time

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm working with multithreading + classes :

```
import time
class CounterThread(threading.Thread):    
   def __init__(self,queue, obj)
       self.obj = obj

   def run(self):
      while True:
         result = self.process()
         self.out_queue.put(result)
         time.sleep(self.obj['wait_Time'])

   def process(self):
      results = ''
      subprocess.check_output(<command> , shell=True) #command for starting sample
      time.sleep(self.obj['sample_Time'])
      status_results = subprocess.check_output(<command>, shell=True) #reads sample output
      lines = status_results.splitlines()
      for lines in lines :
         words = line.split()
         if words[0] == 'Node' :
            results += ('Node=' + words[1] + '\n')
         else if words[0] == 'End-Time' :
            results += 0'End-Time=' + words[1] + ' ' + words[2] + '\n')
      subprocess.check_output(<command>, shell=True) #deletes sample 
      return results
```

the line `time.sleep(self.obj['sample_Time'])` is where I receive the unboundLocalError. I'm fairly certain it's a scope issue, but have no idea how to fix it. if i remove that line, the code runs fine.

Here is the trace back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/software/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 808 in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "counter_extraction.py", line 29, in run
    result = self.process()
  File "counter_extract.py", line 42, in process
    time.sleep(self.obj['sample_Time'])
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'time' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Please update the question and add the complete traceback.

Comment: Updated to add the traceback! Thanks.

Comment: What is the body of the `process` method?

Comment: For debugging you can try `import time as _time` then `_time.sleep(...)`.

Comment: updated the body. @CasualDemon for some reason that fixed it. Not sure why. I didn't have any local variables inside of the process method named time so that was really weird...

Comment: @TimAcorda I Know how it goes, to find weirdness like that will probably take using PDB to backtrace it. Hope ya find the root cause as some point :)

Comment: This can't possibly be the actual code, as `results += 0'End-Time=' + words[1] + ' ' + words[2] + '\n')` has multiple things wrong with the syntax.